# Split the string in a list and match the last splitted string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list of this

```
| 0x60000000 | _loc_NO_BOOL_CONST_GROUP  
| 0x60000020 | _loc_NO_BOOL_GROUP  
| 0x60000020 | _loc_NO_BOOL_TEXT_GROUP    
| 0x6000ffe0 | _loc_NE_BOOL_GROUP  
| 0x6000ffe0 | _loc_NE_BOOL_TEXT_GROUP    
| 0x60010000 | _loc_NO_FIXED_DATA_GROUP   
| 0x60013dc0 | _loc_NE_BOOL_CONST_GROUP   
| 0x60013dc0 | _loc_NE_FIXED_DATA_GROUP
```

I need to split `_loc_NO_` and `_loc_NE_` and have to match splitted LAST STRING , if
match found, return the corresponding value.

suppose in `_loc_NO_BOOL_CONST_GROUP` we splited `_loc_NO_` and last string is `BOOL_CONST_GROUP`
similary in `_loc_NE_BOOL_CONST_GROUP` we splited `_loc_NE_` and last string is `BOOL_CONST_GROUP`

both the string is matching so now, I have to return the corresponding value i.e. "0x60000000" and "0x60013dc0"

so the output should be like:
BOOL_CONST_GROUP = first address value (i.e. 0x60000000), 2nd address value (i.e. 0x60013dc0).

likewise BOOL_TEXT_GROUP = first address value, 2nd address value

Comment: What do you mean by _this_, is it a `text file`, `iostream` or `string` data ?

Comment: @sushanth yes ,a text file

Comment: What is that you have tried so far & where is it you have got stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

To my mind this is a good place to use regex. Here's a full working solution with some additional restraints inferred from your examples.

Inferred rules:

- you're looking for valid hex values which in this case should only be lowercase
- the instruction is the last item on each line in your data file
- your data is in a datafile.txt

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict

strings_to_find = ['_loc_NO_', '_loc_NE_']

pat = re.compile(
      r'\| (?P<location>0x[0-9a-f]{8}) ' +
      r'\| (?P<instruction>%s)' % '|'.join(strings_to_find) +
      r'(?P<instruction_detail>.*?)$',
      re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

with open('datafile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

results = defaultdict(list)

matches = pat.finditer(data)
for m in matches:
    results[m.group('instruction_detail')].append(m.group('location'))

for k, v in results.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: I don't follow. Are you saying this doesn't work exactly as presented? Is that because you're needing to group the outputs?

Comment: the last 4th line of inferred rule is  output should be like:
BOOL_CONST_GROUP = first address value (i.e. 0x60000000), 2nd address value (i.e. 0x60013dc0). 

likewise BOOL_TEXT_GROUP = first address value, 2nd address value..  i need these two values for the further calculation.

Comment: updated to reflect your grouping by instruction_detail